# CSS: Gap between images

Tags: css

I want to make gap between all of these images. 
Picutre 1: http://wrzuc.se/images/52bc941a1dd6a.jpg

To make something like these.. (Picture 2)
Picture 2: http://wrzuc.se/images/52bc949dd19bf.png

How to do this ?
Please help!

I Greet.

Comment: Why can't you add padding/margin?

Comment: What's your HTML, are we supposed to guess what you're working with..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#jakisdiv img {
    margin-right:20px;
} 
#jakisdiv img:last-child {
    margin-right:0 !important;
}
```